# Google Maps Style, Visibility Off, and Performance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've done preliminary searches to find out if there's a positive impact on performance when a Google Map is loaded with some of its features styled with `visibility : 'off'`.

> Is there a performance impact when style properties, like visibility,
>   are toggled?

*The map/s appear to feel "lighter" when `visibility` is disabled, but I haven't found any documentation that confirms this.*

Answer (score 2):

It should improve the performance when you hide clickable elements, e.g. poi, because they not only need to be rendered, they also need some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not see performance improvement.

On the contrary, the custom styled maps require custom tiles, which might take longer than a standard map.

As for the clickable elements ("poi") there should not be a significant difference either if you are just panning and zooming the map.